# How to use NaN values as a hue with a defined color in seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart, nan

Assuming I have a DataFrame (`df`) similar to the one in the image below, with missing values in Score column:

[image]

I would like to plot a horizontal seaborn barplot, with Pvalue on the x-axis and colors of the bars corresponding to Score. Even if I define a colormap and tell it to display NaNs as black bars, they are not shown at all.

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import cm

bwrNan = copy(cm.get_cmap('bwr'))
bwrNan.set_bad('black')
cm.register_cmap("mycmap", bwrNan)
```

```py
sns.barplot(data=df, x='Pvalue', y='Labels', hue='Score', palette='mycmap', linewidth=2, edgecolor='k', dodge=False)
```

[image]

On the other hand, if I try to use the same data in a seaborn heatmap I get the correct colors:

```py
sns.heatmap(data=df[['Score']], cmap='mycmap')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about a quick `for` loop:

```
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    color = 'k' if np.isnan(r['Score']) else bwrNan(r['Score'])
    plt.barh(r['Labels'],r['Pvalue'], color=color, edgecolor='k', alpha=0.6)
```

Output:

[image]